# ActionFilterAttribute - A potentially dangerous Request.Form value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have an auditing system in place that is failing when form values contain HTML.

I have added the `[AllowHtml]` attribute to the model property in question, and have tried adding `[ValidateInput(false)]` to the controller action, as well as using the `Unvalidated()` extension method on `HttpRequestBase`.

None of this is preventing the error.  The line of code it fails on (in the auditing code, `OnActionExecuting()` of the derived `ActionFilterAttribute`) is:

```
return Json.Encode(new { request.Cookies, request.Headers, request.Files, request.Form, request.QueryString, request.Params });
```

Error is:

> A first chance exception of type
>   'System.Web.HttpRequestValidationException' occurred in System.Web.dll
>
> Additional information: A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was
>   detected from the client (Note="`<p>test</p>`").

"Note" being the model property with `[AllowHtml]` on it.

Any ideas on how I can prevent this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's important to understand the order of operations in the ASP.NET MVC pipeline.  Your `OnActionExecuting` method gets called before the action in your controller even begins.  If your controller action hasn't executed, that means your `ValidateInput` annotation isn't being considered.  It also means the model binding hasn't taken place, so your `AllowHtml` annotation isn't considered.  At this point, you've just got access to the basic `Form` collection, and when you try to access the data by serializing via `Json.Encode()` the security protection of ASP.NET is still kicking in.

To solve the issue you could either disable request validation entirely in the Web.config (not recommended), or give your JSON serialization more attention.  To do so, you will have to call `Unvalidated()` when unwrapping the value of the property:

```
return Json.Encode(new {
    request.Cookies,
    request.Headers,
    request.Files,
    new {
        Note = Request.Unvalidated().Form["Note"]
        //Add any other properties you care about here
    },
    request.Form,
    request.QueryString,
    request.Params
 });
```

Comment: The pipeline order of operations makes total sense, thanks.  My issue is that I can't reference specific properties as this attribute is applied to various action methods across controllers.  I have tried replacing request.Form with request.Unvalidated.Form but this is not resolving the issue.

Comment: In that case I would have your action filter attribute take in a parameter (perhaps a `string[]`) which specifies the property names you don't want validated.  Given that, you can iterate over the string array and look for properties using something like: `Request.Unvalidated().Form[propertyName]`.

Comment: [Allow HTML], [ValidateInput(false)] not works ,onActionExecuted method, when tried to get the parameters from request, so tried to get parameters from Request.Unvalidated